# Changing drive format and restoring an Macintosh via Time Machine

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, partitioning, formatting

Recently I had to take my Mac into repair and they had to wipe everything I thought I had my data mainly photos backed up on my Western Digital Elements hard drive through Time Machine. Once back home—after the Mac was repaired—I tried to transfer data back and restore my Mac but it’s come up with that case sensitive. I just want to know if I can convert the hard drive back to a format so I can restore the photos?

Comment: Yes this is correct

Comment: I would very seriously question the credentials of any repair shop that had to 'wipe everything' & then formatted as case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

> …I tried to transfer data back and restore my Mac but it’s come up with
>   that case sensitive.

This description of the issue confuses me a bit, but I think I understand what has happened. When you took your Mac in for repair and they had to wipe everything and now when you took it back home you found out the system hard drive is now formatted as a case sensitive volume which is not the Mac OS X default and not what you want.

You can reformat the hard drive to be case insensitive which is the default. You would need to boot into recovery mode. Just reboot or cold start your Mac and hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> and then choose the “Recovery” partition as your startup disk. Or reboot or cold start your Mac and hold down <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys which would boot you straight into the “Recovery” partition.

Once that is done, launch “Disk Utility” and reformat the system drive so it is “Mac OS Extended (Journaled)”—see picture—which is the default case-insensitive option for all Mac disks.

[image]

After that formatting happens, your drive will be back to a case insensitive state and ready for recovery.

But past any of that, if they formatted your drive as case sensitive, there is a small risk they did not partition the drive as having “GUID Partition Table” which is what Mac OS X wants/needs. So you might have to repartition that drive with a “GUID Partition Table” and make sure the formatting is “Mac OS Extended (Journaled)” to ensure all is in working order.

That said, I need to be 100% clear that if you reformat your system drive you would have to reinstall Mac OS X again. Not too clear if the folks who did repairs reinstalled Mac OS X for you, but you are now going to have to start from scratch again. Or maybe I am unclear about how “Time Machine” would handle recovery like this, so maybe it would just restore your whole past system as it was before? Just things to keep in mind.